# Print the Search pattern in awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I would like to print the matching search pattern and then calculate average row. Best would be an expample:

input file:

```
chr17   41275978    41276294    BRCA1_ex02_01   278 
chr17   41275978    41276294    BRCA1_ex02_01   279 
chr17   41275978    41276294    BRCA1_ex02_01   280 
chr17   41275978    41276294    BRCA1_ex02_02   281 
chr17   41275978    41276294    BRCA1_ex02_02   282 
chr17   41275978    41276294    BRCA1_ex02_03   283 
chr17   41275978    41276294    BRCA1_ex02_03   284 
chr17   41275978    41276294    BRCA1_ex02_03   285 
chr17   41275978    41276294    BRCA1_ex02_04   286 
chr17   41275978    41276294    BRCA1_ex02_04   287 
chr17   41275978    41276294    BRCA1_ex02_04   288
```

I wana extract in bash loop (for example) just the same 4th column:

output1:

```
chr17   41275978    41276294    BRCA1_ex02_01   278 
chr17   41275978    41276294    BRCA1_ex02_01   279 
chr17   41275978    41276294    BRCA1_ex02_01   280
```

output2:

```
chr17   41275978    41276294    BRCA1_ex02_02   281 
chr17   41275978    41276294    BRCA1_ex02_02   282
```

output3:

```
chr17   41275978    41276294    BRCA1_ex02_03   283 
chr17   41275978    41276294    BRCA1_ex02_03   284 
chr17   41275978    41276294    BRCA1_ex02_03   285
```

an so on so on.. Then calculate average for 5th column is very easy:

awk 'END{sum+=$5}{print NR/sum}' in_file.txt

In my case, there are thousands lines BRCA1_exXX_XX - so any idea hot to split it?

Paul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the entries are sorted by the 4th column as in your given data, you could do it like this:

```
awk '

  $4 != prev {              # if this line's 4th column is different from the previous line
    if (cnt > 0)            # if count of lines is greater than 0
      print prev, sum / cnt #   print the average
    prev = $4               # save previous 4th column
    sum = $5                # initialize sum to column 5
    cnt = 1                 # initialize count to 1
    next                    # go to next line
  }

  {
    sum += $5               # accumulate total of 5th column
    ++cnt                   # increment count of lines
  }

  END {
    if (cnt > 0)             # if count > 0 (avoid divide by 0 on empty file)
      print prev, sum / cnt  #   print the average for the last line
  }

' file
```

Comment: This assumes the entries are always in order.

Comment: Wau it looks that works :-) thank you! It is possible to explain? And can I add to third column standard deviation value?

Comment: @EtanReisner Yes, it assumes the entries are sorted by the 4th column, as in the given data.

Comment: Just add a test for `n` in the END section too to avoid a divide by zero error on empty files.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will do what you want.

```
awk '{
    # Keep running sum of fifth column based on value of fourth column.
    v[$4]+=$5;
    # Keep count of lines with similar fourth column values.
    n[$4]++
}

END {
    # Loop over all the values we saw and print out their fourth columns and the sum of the fifth columns.
    for (val in n) {
        print val ": " v[val] / n[val]
    }
}' $file
```

Comment: Never use the letter `l` as a variable name as it looks far too much like the number `1`. Completely indistinguishable in some fonts.

Comment: @EdMorton Fair enough. I was using it to stand in for "line" but that doesn't really make much sense in that context either. Editing.

Comment: This outputs the data in a random order.

Comment: Yes, it outputs in random order because awk doesn't (depending on version) have a good way to print that out in a sorted fashion and I don't have @EdMorton's comprehensive knowledge of awk version quirks. With recent gnu awk versions `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` can be used, with older gnu awk versions `asort`/`asorti` can be used, in other versions a magic environment variable exists, beyond that I don't know. And there is always the fallback of `| sort`.

Comment: Assuming you want the output in the same order as the input, just move `n[$4]++` out of the current action section and add a new condition+action of `!n[$4]++{ keys[++numKeys] = $4 }` and then make your loop in the END section `for (k=1; k<=numKeys; k++) { val = keys[k]; print val ": " v[val] / n[val] }`. As you mention, only recent GNU awk versions let you control the order of array indices selected when using the `in` operator, but it's rarely needed.

Comment: Please do you have any idea how to put there standard deviation and min and max value?

Comment: @Petr Keeping min and max values by fourth column just requires some extra keys (or arrays) and some extra logic in the main action. Doing standard deviation will require some extra work using those values in the END block.